# Testcafe and concurrency

Tags: testing, concurrency, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I execute tests with testcafe concurrently (flag -c 2) to check a website with user authentication.

My tests need to use a different user regarding the "thread" where they are executed.

Does there is a solution to detect a "thread" number inside a test ?

Comment: The concurrent mode doesn't determine which test for which browser instance will be launched. Let's clarify your test scenario. Do you want to run some randomly picked tests for the first user and other tests for the second user?

Comment: I would like detect in test if i use the first browser instance or the second.

Comment: Finally i found a workaround with `t.testRun.browserConnection.id` that return the Id of the browser instance. So I can associate a user to this Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `t.testRun.browserConnection.id` that returns the Id of the browser instance.